# How to troubleshoot Composer autoload in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, codeigniter-3, autoloader

I am new to using **Composer in Codeigniter** and have read all I can to try and fix my issue, but are coming up short. The autoloader seems to to be autoloading? So here is where I am stuck:

- I have installed a composer.
- Required the MPDF package using `composer require pdf/mpdf`
- I did that from the root of my project, so the vendor folder, as well as the composer.json file is on the root of my project
- In my config/config.php file, I changed the `composer_autoload` value to 
  `$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH . "/vendor/autoload.php";`

Then I created a simple function in my default controller like this:

```
function m_pdf() {
        $mpdf = new mPDF();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
        $mpdf->Output();
    }
```

But when I run it, I get an error: **Message: Class 'mPDF' not found**

I have tried moving everything to the application folder, and change the value in the config file to TRUE, I have tried calling the autoloader from the function itself, but no luck.

I feel I am missing something obvious. Maybe some dependencies. As I said, I am new to use the composer. There were some suggestions on the web about running `php composer.phar` but I get an error when I try and run that. Could that be it?

Comment: If you check the [documentation for mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html), their example is: `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();`. You need to use the correct namespace and the correct casing.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson. I have corrected that mistake but continue to have the same problem: ``Message: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found``

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? What do you get if you do: `var_dump(is_file(FCPATH . "/vendor/autoload.php"));`?

Comment: YAY, got it sorted. Seems some form of caching was in play, so after all the changes, and a new browser window, and a few Ctrl+F5s it is finally working. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) in namespace => use correct Mpdf class

**If still not help** => `composer dump-autoload`(reconfigure your composer classMap)

**If dump-autoload not help** =>

- remove `vendor` directory
- `composer install`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions above. I added the correct namespace in the function ``$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf()`` and tried dumping the autoload and deleted the vendor folder, and installed composer again pulling in all the files, but when I run the function I get: **Message: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found**